# Is there a conventional symbol to say that we take the derivative of whatever is left of said symbol?

Tags: derivatives, notation

When calculating derivatives on paper I usually use an arrow to denote that I am taking the derivative of what's left of that arrow. But sometimes for longer calculations or if someone else needs to understand the calculations this becomes unhandy. Is there a conventional symbol to represent this instead? I know that the derivative of $f$ can be denoted by $f'$ or $\frac{df}{dx}$, but what I want is $f =_{symbol} f'$. Even better if we can denote the variable which we differentiate.

Comment: In your last sentence, @'timtam', I guess you rather mean $f '=_{symbol} f$? I'm not sure I'm understanding entirely, but with regards to your last point, if I want to clearly denote the variable with respect to which I am differentiating I would mark this in a subscript, like $\partial_t$ or $\partial_{x_i}$ where $t$-differentiation might be time-differentiation, and $x_i$-differentiation might denote differentiation with respect to the $i$-th spatial component.

Comment: It seems you are looking for a shorthand calculation and not for something that might be used "seriously", e.g., in a publication. It is common to use $|$ or $\|$to denote the operations done with both sides of an equation during equivalence transforms (e.g., $$\begin{align}x^2-2x&=3 &\|\,+1\\x^2-2x+1&=4\end{align}$$) Why not use something like that for your purpose? E.g., $$\begin{align}xe^{-x}&&|\,\frac d{dx}\\e^{-x}-xe^{-x}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps not 100% conventional, but you could maybe use a “maps to” arrow ($\mapsto$) with a “$d/dx$” (or something similar) attached to it? Like this:
$$f \overset{d/dx}{\longmapsto} f'$$

Comment: Yes this is what I was after, thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe obvious, but why don't you just use parentheses? For instace, if you want to differentiate $x\cdot\cos x$, just write $(x\cdot\cos x)'$.

Comment: Maybe obvious, but then I would have to do the brackets around every expression that is equivalent to $x\cdot \cos x$ and that I have used before to derive the expression that I want to differentiate, otherwise the equivalence wouldn't hold anymore.